# Why can't nginx have more than 75 seconds proxy connect wait?

Tags: nginx, proxy

According to this doc [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_connect_timeout), nginx `proxy_connect_timeout` cannot have more than 75seconds delay.

I know its terrible to have an app with that delay, but I am being curious why this exact value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the nginx mailing list (see http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,214595,214597#msg-214597)

> Connect timeout is limited by your OS's SYN retransmit count limit
>   and timeout. Under FreeBSD it's 75s by default (3 retransmits
>   with exponential backoff: 3s + 6s + 12s + 24s), under Linux it's
>   looks like something about 20s by default. Looks like you are
>   hitting this limit.
>
> The only way to enlarge this limit is to tune OS, e.g. on Linux
>   try adjusting net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries sysctl.